# Сортировка даты в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как можно отсортировать ActiveRecord по полю date, что бы отсортировать от самых близких дат. Как в этом запросе, но неподходящие записи выводить в конец сортировки

```
SELECT * FROM tag_events WHERE event_day_start >= now() ORDER BY event_day_start ASC
```

Comment: `Model::find()->orderBy(['date' => SORT_DESC])->all()`

Comment: дата к которой ищем ближайшее вводится пользователем, еще могут быть даты которые так скажем прошли, относительно выбранной даты и в конец сортировки

Comment: Нужно конкретнее формулировать вопрос

Comment: @robertobadjio, согласен, с этим иногда беда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вышло как то так:

```
Events::find()->orderBy([new \yii\db\Expression('CASE WHEN event_day_start >= CURRENT_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, ABS(CURRENT_DATE - event_day_start)')])
```